# Trying to compare date in different rows in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using Google Bigquery to compare date field on two different rows, like this:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvGDb.png)

I would like evaluate the rows that have the same ID and are more than 30 minutes beetween them, but I am not able to compare two different rows beetwen them, and I coul even omit one of them, and count only the equal customerid rows that have more than 30 minutes beetween them...

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I am currently trying to count the distinct records, and to add a column that says if the customer id has a previous access... I am editing to add the sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if the customer accessed last more than 30 minutes before, use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (process_time_A >
        timestamp_add(lag(process_time_A) over (partition by customerId order by process_time_A), interval 30 minute)
       ) as is_more_than_30_minutes
from t
```

Comment: This solution brings me the message:
"Argument 3 to analytic function 'lag' has to be a constant. Found Deref."

Am I missing something?

Comment: @FábioPerecinFoltram . . . Dispensing with it probably still does what you want.  That said, I am really shocked I hadn't seen that before in BigQuery.  I was pretty sure I had used that construct there.  Perhaps it was always with `0`.

Comment: Hello Gordon, thank you very much, I tried again and it worked.
I still have some issues wiht the final countdown, but it´s within the rules of our countdown. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a self join:

```
with joined as (
  select 
    a.*, 
    b.row as other_row,
    b.process_time_A as other_process_time, 
    timestamp_diff(a.process_time_A, b.process_time_A, day) as days_difference 
  from `table` a
  inner join `table` b using(customerID)
)
select * from joined
where days_difference >= 30
```

Comment: Damn, this is clever! I will try and get back here!